# Combine two bitmaps with newCanvas.drawBitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

I have 2 ImageViews within a RelativeLayout, one is a background and one is an image the user can scale and move and place on top of the background. I would next like to combine them preserving the size and position of the top image. So when the user clicks save they get a new image. Is this possible? I am new to processing images in Android. As of now my code combines them but image 2 goes back to its original size and is always centered in image 1.

Any suggestions on where to start? I think I need to save the image 2 as a new bitmap after I scale it. I'm not sure about the position tho?

```
private Bitmap combineBitmap() throws FileNotFoundException {

    Drawable bm1New = adding_toFace.getDrawable();

    xx = adding_toFace.getTranslationX();
    yy = adding_toFace.getTranslationX();
    Bitmap newBitmap = null;

    int w;
    if (bm1.getWidth() >= bm2.getWidth()) {
        w = bm1.getWidth();
    } else {
        w = bm2.getWidth();
    }

    int h;
    if (bm1.getHeight() >= bm2.getHeight()) {
        h = bm1.getHeight();
    } else {
        h = bm2.getHeight();
    }


    Config config = bm1.getConfig();
    if (config == null) {
        config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }



    newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, config);
    Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

    newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, null); 

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAlpha(128);

    //int y = adding_toFace.getTop();
    //int x = adding_toFace.getLeft();
    newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm2, 0, 0, paint);

    return newBitmap;
}// combineBitmap
```

Comment: The 2nd image has an OnTouch lstener that lets you move and scale the 2nd image wherever you want over the 1st image. I need to save the images where the user put them.  Like as if image one was a pic of a face and the 2nd image was a mustache.png The above code works but the 2nd image is always in center of 1st image and always original size(not scaled down size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically this concept is just convert the view into image file,
so that the face image can be background src in the layout, and secondary image can inside the layout, if you dun want the button shown in the image, kindly move the button out of the relative layout will do.

MainActivity.class

```
package com.example.atestapp;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private RelativeLayout relativelayoutview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        relativelayoutview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayoutview);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Bitmap bm = viewToBitmap(relativelayoutview);
                Log.i("MainActivity", "bm: "+bm);

                saveBitmap(bm);
            }

        });

    }

    public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }


    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        try {
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/file.png");
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
            output.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayoutview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/smile"
     >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/huh"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />    

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

add the permission in manifex as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: zeisuke , thanks for that code , but my method already does that. What I want to do is:: Pic one is like a face , pic two is a mustache , user places mustache over face in a specific position then combine the 2 images. 3rd image will be ya know like the persons face with the mustache.

Comment: noted, i modified and attached with another idea, but not sure is it what u want. do update me again :)

Comment: thanks again zeisuke, I think I am getting closer , I have some time to work on it toda.  Ill keep you posted.

Comment: Zeisuke , Dude , Yes , exactly what I was trying to do. Had no idea it was that easy. Very cool method. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageView.
  bitmap 1 as background, bitmap2 as src;
  setTouchListener on this view;
  put any actions you did into a Matrix(move, scale,rotate...)
  via setImageMatrix()  apply to imageView; 
  finally,get Matrix by imageView.getImageMatrix()  to do the combination work.
  just an idea.

Comment: thanks ,  I never played with any of this stuff, Ill go look at the documentation on all that and give it a shot.